# PHP Classes and Uncaught PDOException error

Tags: php, mysql

I have been away from PHP for a good few years and coding an application up using Classes etc... however, I am getting the following stack errors and a little lost to where I am going wrong as more or less replicated from another class so not sure what I am missing...

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 1 in
>   /home/ambcom/public_html/tracking/login/class/mailtranslations.php:17
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/ambcom/public_html/tracking/login/class/mailtranslations.php(17):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   /home/ambcom/public_html/tracking/admin/emailtranslations.php(11):
>   MailTranslations->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in
>   /home/ambcom/public_html/tracking/login/class/mailtranslations.php on
>   line 17

**dbconfig.php file**

```
$tbl_prefix = ""; //Prefix for all database tables

$tbl_members = $tbl_prefix."members";
$tbl_memberinfo = $tbl_prefix."member_info";
$tbl_admins = $tbl_prefix."admins";
$tbl_attempts = $tbl_prefix."login_attempts";
$tbl_deleted = $tbl_prefix."deleted_members";
$tbl_tokens = $tbl_prefix."tokens";
$tbl_cookies = $tbl_prefix."cookies";
$tbl_appConfig = $tbl_prefix."app_config";
$tbl_mailLog = $tbl_prefix."mail_log";
$tbl_mailLog = $tbl_prefix."sms_log";
$tbl_mailTranslations = $tbl_prefix."mail_translations";
$tbl_smsTranslations = $tbl_prefix."sms_translations";
```

**/login/class/mailtranslations.php**

```
<?php
/**
* Handles application configuration settings stored in database `mail_translations` table
**/
class MailTranslations extends DbConn
{
  /**
  * Primarily instantiated in `login/partials/pagehead.php`. Meant to be instantiated once to minimize unnecessary database calls.
  * In any page where `pagehead.php` is included, settings can be pulled as such: `$this->setting_name` where `setting_name` corresponds to "setting" entry in `app_config` database table.
  **/
  function __construct() {

      parent::__construct();

      $sql = "SELECT setting, value FROM ".$this->tbl_mailTranslations;
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      $settings = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);

      //Pulls all properties from database
      foreach ($settings as $key => $value) {

          $this->{$key} = $value;
      }

      $this->signin_url = $settings['base_url'].'/login';

      if ($this->from_email == '') {
          $this->from_email = $this->admin_email;
      }

  }
  /**
  * Pulls single translation statically from database without invoking new MailTranslations object. Meant to be used in pages where `pagehead.php` is not included.
  * Calls can be made like so: MailTranslations::pullTranslation('setting_name', 'db_var_type', 'lang')
  *
  * `setting_name` corresponds to "setting" entry in `mail_translations` table, and `db_var_type` should be desired db type such as `unsigned` for integers, `varchar`, etc.
  **/
  public static function pullTranslation($setting, $type = 'varchar', $lang = 'English')
  {

      $db = new DbConn;
      try {
      if ($type === 'varchar') {
          $sql = "SELECT value FROM ".$db->tbl_mailTranslations." WHERE setting = :setting LIMIT 1";
      } else {
          $sql = "SELECT CAST(value AS ".$type.") FROM ".$db->tbl_mailTranslations." WHERE setting = :setting AND lang = :lang LIMIT 1";
      }
          $stmt = $db->conn->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->bindParam(':setting', $setting);
          $stmt->bindParam(':lang', $lang);
          $stmt->execute();
          $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

      } catch (PDOException $e) {

          $result[0] = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
      }

      unset($db);

      return $result[0];

  }
  /**
  * Updates array of settings.
  * Calls can be made like so: $obj->updateMultiMailTranslations(array("setting1"=>"value1", "setting2"=>"value2", "etc"=>"etc"), "lang")
  **/
  public function updateMultiMailTranslations($settingArray, $lang = "English")
  {
      try {
          foreach ($settingArray as $setting=>$value) {

              try {

                  $sql = "UPDATE ".$this->tbl_mailTranslations." SET value = :value WHERE setting = :setting AND lang = :lang";

                  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
                  $stmt->bindParam(":value", $value);
                  $stmt->bindParam(":setting", $setting);
                  $stmt->bindParam(":lang", $lang);
                  $stmt->execute();

              } catch (PDOException $e) {
                  $result['status'] = false;
                  $result['message'] = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
              }
          }

          $result['status'] = true;
          $result['message'] = "<div class=\"alert alert-success alert-dismissable\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>Changes Saved Successfully</div>";

      } catch (Exception $x) {
          $result['status'] = "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>Your account has been created, but you cannot log in until it has been verified</div>";
          $result['message'] = $x->getMessage();

      }

      return $result;
  }
  /**
  * Pulls all mail translations statically from database with descriptions, lang, and input types. Meant to be used specifically in `admin/editconfig.php` page.
  * Calls can be made like so: Translations::pullAllMailTranslations()
  **/
  public static function pullAllMailTranslations()
  {
      if ($_SESSION["admin"] == 1) {

          $db = new DbConn;

          try {
          $sql = "SELECT setting, value, description, type, lang FROM ".$db->tbl_mailTranslations." where type != 'hidden' order by -sortorder desc";

          $stmt = $db->conn->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->execute();
          $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

          } catch (PDOException $e) {

              $result = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
          }

      } else {
          $result = "You must be an admin to use this method";
      }

      return $result;
  }

}
```

**admin/emailtranslations.php file**

> Line 11: $conf = new MailTranslations;

```
<?php
/**
* Configuration edit page
*
* Tags correspond to setting name, hover over them for setting description
**/
$pagetype = 'superadminpage';
$title = 'Email Translations';
require '../login/partials/pagehead.php';

$conf = new MailTranslations;
$settingsArr = $conf->pullAllMailTranslations();

//Gets langs from settings array
foreach ($settingsArr as $key => $value) {
 $groupedArr[$value[4]][] = $value;
}

?>
```

Comment: The problem is the query that you're constructing.  Try dumping the value of `$sql` before you prepare it and see what it is.

Comment: Also note that `:lang` will exist on the second query, so you won't be able to bind it if it uses the first query.

Comment: 2 mins guys, just trying now....

Comment: ahhh might explain why.... string(27) "SELECT setting, value FROM " just looking at why now :)

Comment: You use `$this-> tbl_mailTranslations ` in the constructor, and `$db-> tbl_mailTranslations ` in your function.

Comment: Only used that as its used like that in other class templates, I added the translations one as a new addition so assumed would work the same so its not picking up the new one i added for some reason.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: I would i guess in normal circumstances however been working on this application for 2 weeks and need to deliver by tomorrow that is the problem, just dont have time. But just checked the class file i replicated for this new class file and construct uses $this-> and functions $db-> so is the same.

Comment: Ahh think i have found the issue, there is a class file called dbconn.php and see lists tables in there as well so might be why.... just trying now

Comment: Ok yep that was the issue, I am facing another one but that is resolved now... thanks guys for helping out.